# How to get correct location address using latitude & longitude in typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I tried to get location address from latitude and longitude when clicking on map.
In here I could be able to get latitude and longitude when clicking on map.

then I tired to get address using below function,

```
getCurrentLocation(lat,lng): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.get("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+lng+"&sensor=true")
            .map(response => response.json())
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                return Observable.throw(error.json());
            });
}
```

I imported followings for my `typescript` function,

```
import { } from 'googlemaps';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
```

I am confused to get address from this.

Have any ideas ?

Comment: were you able to get any response from this endpoint?

Comment: @AjanthaBandara : Now I am getting this, {
   "error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}

Comment: This is a paid service.  If you are going to use this as a free service there is a maximum request quota per day for this API. You can find all the detail from below link
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start

Comment: @AjanthaBandara : I already have Google API key. I want to pass latitude and longitude only. Both of examples are included with address. How I can use my Google API key to full fill that object ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. I Test the URL with parameters and working fine.

```
getCurrentLocation(lat,lng): Observable<any> {
    const YOUR_API_KEY = "put the api key here";
    const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${lat},${lng}&key=${YOUR_API_KEY}`;
    return this._http.get(url)
         .map(response => response.json())
          .catch(error => {
               console.log(error);
               return Observable.throw(error.json());
          });
    }
```

Comment: OK. I will try on this.